# Program multiplies integers by a factor of 10

Tags: c++

In Chapter 3 of *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++* Bjarne Stroustrup asks you to "write a program that takes an operation followed by two operands and outputs the result. For example: "

```
+ 100 3.14 
* 4 5
```

Here's what I've done.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

// This little program does addition, substraction, multiplication, and division as long as the number of operators doesn't exceed two.

int main()

{

cout << "Bonvole enigu du nombrojn post unu el tiuj ĉi matematikaj operaciloj: +,-, *, or /  \n";
cout << "Please enter two numbers preceded by either of these mathematical operators: +,-, *, or /  \n";

string s;
int a, b;
cin >> s >> a >> b;
    if (s == "+") {
        cout << a + b;
        }
    else if (s == "-") {
        cout << a - b;
        }
    else if (s == "*") {
        cout << a * b;
        }
    else (s == "/"); {
        cout << a / b << "\n";
        }
return 0;
}
```

The results are all wrong.

```
@localhost ~]$ ./a.out 
Bonvole enigu du nombrojn post unu el tiuj ĉi matematikaj operaciloj: +,-, *, or /  
Please enter two numbers preceded by either of these mathematical operators: +,-, *, or /  
+ 2 3 
50
[chetan@localhost ~]$ ./a.out 
Bonvole enigu du nombrojn post unu el tiuj ĉi matematikaj operaciloj: +,-, *, or /  
Please enter two numbers preceded by either of these mathematical operators: +,-, *, or /  
- 3 2 
11
[chetan@localhost ~]$ ./a.out 
Bonvole enigu du nombrojn post unu el tiuj ĉi matematikaj operaciloj: +,-, *, or /  
Please enter two numbers preceded by either of these mathematical operators: +,-, *, or /  
* 2 3 
60
[chetan@localhost ~]$ ./a.out 
Bonvole enigu du nombrojn post unu el tiuj ĉi matematikaj operaciloj: +,-, *, or /  
Please enter two numbers preceded by either of these mathematical operators: +,-, *, or /  
/ 3 2 
1
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
else (s == "/"); {
    cout << a / b << "\n";
    }
```

This should read

```
else if (s == "/") {
    cout << a / b << "\n";
    }
```

(note the added `if` and the removed semicolon.)

Your current code can be reformatted as follows:

```
else {
    (s == "/");
}
cout << a / b << "\n";
```

The `else` clause is effectively a no-op since it's just a comparison, and the final `cout` statement is executed unconditionally, irrespective of the chosen operator.

Comment: This is the error message I receive if I remove that semi-colon (;) after else (s == "/").

@localhost ~]$ g++ -std=c++11 /home/chetan/Programs/Bjarne/bjarne_c3.cpp 
/home/chetan/Programs/Bjarne/bjarne_c3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/chetan/Programs/Bjarne/bjarne_c3.cpp:29:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
     else (s == "/") {
                     ^